# Math Expression Simplification f#

Tags: recursion, f#, f#-interactive

I'm working on a mathematical expression simplifier (rather basic, no exponents, logs, roots, fractions etc) and I have it mostly working. Of the 19 tests I've used 14 of them pass. For the 5 remaining, I have written multiple other statements in my simplify function but it doesn't seem to change a thing.

Below is code (copy and paste into an interpreter and it works just fine)

```
    //expression types 
type Expression =
    | X
    | Y
    | Const of float
    | Neg of Expression
    | Add of Expression * Expression
    | Sub of Expression * Expression
    | Mul of Expression * Expression

// formats string 
let exprToString expr =
    let rec recExprStr parens expr =
        let lParen = if parens then "(" else ""
        let rParen = if parens then ")" else ""
        match expr with
        | X -> "x"
        | Y -> "y"
        | Const n -> n.ToString()
        | Neg e -> lParen + "-" + recExprStr true e + rParen
        | Add (e1, e2) -> lParen + recExprStr true e1 + "+" + recExprStr true e2 + rParen
        | Sub (e1, e2) -> lParen + recExprStr true e1 + "-" + recExprStr true e2 + rParen
        | Mul (e1, e2) -> lParen + recExprStr true e1 + "*" + recExprStr true e2 + rParen
    recExprStr false expr

//simplification function 
let rec simplify expr =
    match expr with
    //addition 
    | Add(Const(ex1), Const(ex2)) -> Const(ex1 + ex2)
    | Add(ex1, Const(0.)) -> ex1 |> simplify
    | Add(Const(0.), ex1) -> ex1 |> simplify
    | Add(Const(num), ex1) -> Add(ex1, Const(num)) |> simplify
    | Add(ex1, Neg(ex2)) -> Sub(ex1, ex2) |> simplify
    | Add(Neg(ex1), ex2) -> Sub(ex2, ex1) |> simplify
    //subtraction 
    | Sub(Const(num1), Const(num2)) -> Const(num1 - num2)
    | Sub(ex1, Const(0.)) -> ex1 |> simplify
    | Sub(Const(0.), ex1) -> Neg(ex1) |> simplify
    //multiplication 
    | Mul(Const(num1), Const(num2)) -> Const(num1 * num2)
    | Mul(ex1, Const(1.)) -> ex1 |> simplify
    | Mul(Const(1.), ex1) -> ex1 |> simplify
    | Mul(ex1, Const(0.)) -> Const(0.)
    | Mul(Const(0.), ex1) -> Const(0.)
    | Mul(ex1, Const(num1)) -> Mul(Const(num1), ex1) |> simplify
    | Mul(Neg(ex1), ex2) -> Neg(Mul(ex1, ex2)) |> simplify
    | Mul(ex1, Neg(ex2)) -> Neg(Mul(ex1, ex2)) |> simplify
    //negation involving a number
    | Neg(Const(0.)) -> Const(0.)
    | Neg(Neg(ex1)) -> ex1 |> simplify
    | _ -> expr

//Tests
printfn "---Provided Tests---"
let t1 = Add (Const 5.0, Const 3.0)
let t2 = Sub (Const 5.0, Const 3.0)
let t3 = Mul (Const 5.0, Const 3.0)
let t4 = Neg (Const 4.0)
let t5 = Neg (Const -9.0)
let t6 = Add (X, Const 0.0)
let t7 = Add (Const 0.0, Y)
let t8 = Sub (X, Const 0.0)
let t9 = Sub (Const 0.0, Y)
let t10 = Sub (Y, Y)
let t11 = Mul (X, Const 0.0)
let t12 = Mul (Const 0.0, Y)
let t13 = Mul (X, Const 1.0)
let t14 = Mul (Const 1.0, Y)
let t15 = Neg (Neg X)
let t16 = Sub (Mul (Const 1.0, X), Add (X, Const 0.0))
let t17 = Add (Mul (Const 4.0, Const 3.0), Sub (Const 11.0, Const 5.0))
let t18 = Sub (Sub (Add (X, Const 1.0), Add (X, Const 1.0)), Add (Y, X))
let t19 = Sub (Const 0.0, Neg (Mul (Const 1.0, X)))

//Output goes here! 
//5 + 3 = 0
printfn "t1  Correct: 8\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t1))
//5-3 = 2
printfn "t2  Correct: 2\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t2))
//5 * 3 = 15
printfn "t3  Correct: 15\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t3))
//-(4) = -4
printfn "t4  Correct: -4\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t4))
//-(-9) = 9
printfn "t5  Correct: 9\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t5))
//x + 0 = x
printfn "t6  Correct: x\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t6))
//0 + y = y
printfn "t7  Correct: y\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t7))
//x - 0 = x
printfn "t8  Correct: x\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t8))
//0 - y = -y
printfn "t9  Correct: -y\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t9))
//y - y = 0
printfn "t10  Correct: 0\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t10))
//x * 0 = 0
printfn "t11  Correct: 0\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t11))
//0 * y = 0
printfn "t12  Correct: 0\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t12))
//x * 1 = x
printfn "t13  Correct: x\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t13))
//1 * y = y
printfn "t14  Correct: y\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t14))
//-(-x) = x
printfn "t15  Correct: x\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t15))
// (1 * x) - (x + 0) = 0
printfn "t16  Correct: 0\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t16))
//(4 * 3) + (11 - 5) = 18
printfn "t17  Correct: 18\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t17))
// ((x + 1) - (x + 1)) - (y+x) = -y -x
printfn "t18  Correct: -y -x\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t18))
// 0 - (-(1 * x)) = x
printfn "t19  Correct: x\t\tActual: %s" (exprToString (simplify t19))
// (x + 1) *  (-2y + x)
```

The output of the program is as follows, I have marked the 6 tests that fail (correct is the proper answer, actual is what i'm returning)

```
t1  Correct: 8          Actual: 8
t2  Correct: 2          Actual: 2
t3  Correct: 15         Actual: 15
t4  Correct: -4         Actual: -4
t5  Correct: 9          Actual: --9 //FAILS 
t6  Correct: x          Actual: x
t7  Correct: y          Actual: y
t8  Correct: x          Actual: x
t9  Correct: -y         Actual: -y
t10  Correct: 0         Actual: y-y //FAILS
t11  Correct: 0         Actual: 0
t12  Correct: 0         Actual: 0
t13  Correct: x         Actual: x
t14  Correct: y         Actual: y
t15  Correct: x         Actual: x
t16  Correct: 0         Actual: (1*x)-(x+0)          //FAILS
t17  Correct: 18                Actual: (4*3)+(11-5) //FAILS
t18  Correct: -(y + x)             Actual: ((x+1)-(x+1))-(y+x) //FAILS 
t19  Correct: x         Actual: x
```

I'm a bit perplexed as to how I might solve the final 4 (16,17,18) but It seems to me like what I have for #5 and #10 should work.

For test 5, I included `| Neg(Neg(ex1)) -> ex1 |> simplify` which I thought would catch my double negative but doesn't.

For test 10, I figured something like `| Sub(ex1, ex2) -> (ex1 - ex2)` would work, but it turns out that's not even valid syntax.

I've looked through a half dozen or so resources on simplification, and even copying and pasting some of their work my tests still fail. It know I must just be missing a case or two, but I'm pulling my hair trying to figure what I might have left out! I greatly appreciate any input!

(Original post had a test 20, I have since removed it for answer simplification purposes. Given my current code, I realized I couldn't possibly simplify it)

Comment: Can I just say I love your little ad-hoc testing solution? :)

Comment: So for a quick first look, your test #5 is failing because you didn't implement the logic for negation of constants. You only handle `-0` and `-(-n)`. You'll need a case that looks like `| Neg(n) -> -n`

Comment: In general I'd start with some really simple operations first, get them working on cases involving literals, then attempt to generalize via recursion from there. You'll probably end up with simpler code

Comment: For #10, you want to have a case that uses a `when` guard in your match: `Sub(ex1, ex2) when ex1 = ex2 -> Const(0.)` might do it, but that would fail on expressions like (1+2) - (0+3). So I'd probably try `Sub(ex1, ex2) when simplify ex1 = simplify ex2 -> Const(0.)`, which will probably cover both test #10 and also test #16.

Comment: @rmunn I never thought of it that way. I'll give it a shot

Comment: And test #17 might work if you add a match line like `Add(ex1, ex2) -> let ex1s = simplify ex1; let ex2s = simplify ex2; simplify (Add(ex1s, ex2s))`. (Put newlines where I put semicolons: I only used semicolons because in Stack Overflow comments you can't have newlines.) But beware of infinite loops when doing something like that: maybe you should add a check like `if ex1s = ex1 && ex2s = ex2 then Add(ex1s, ex2s) else simplify (Add(ex1s, ex2s))`.

Comment: @Podo - Have you tried http://exercism.io/ yet? Its F# track is the most complete track of any of the available languages, and has some really good exercises. I mention this because what you're doing reminds me of some of my favorite exercises from that site, like http://exercism.io/exercises/fsharp/wordy/readme.

Comment: @rmunn No, pretty much everything is youtube and fsharpforfunandprofit, then little blogs I find while googling here and there. Thanks for the share, I'll be sure to check it out. It's funny, I bought a book for Haskell, as well as one for general functional programming, but I just like F# more.

Comment: @rmunn this entire experience has been a practice in avoiding infinite loops. That will be nothing new ;)

Comment: It would be useful (& fun) to printfn " derive %A" (exprToString expr) at the top of simplify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5: `Neg(Const -9)` does not get simplified. It is not a negative of a negative. You need a rule `Neg(Const x) -> Const(-x)` to replace the `Neg(Const 0.)` one.

10: `Sub(x,y) when y = x -> Const(0)`

16: You are not simplifying the inner parts. I would do this before simplifying the outer parts. E.g. `Sub(x,y) -> let x',y' = simplify x, simplify y` and then `match x',y' with....`

17: Solution to 16 would fix this.

18: Solution to 10 and 16 would fix this.

Also I cannot resist suggesting  `let t = [Add (Const 5.0, Const 3.0); Sub (Const 5.0, Const 3.0)...]` and then `t |> List.iteri ...` .

I am using an ad hoc algebraic simplifier which does OK but would like to create a much more serious one. If anyone is seriously intersted in working on this please let me know.

Comment: For #10, you'd need `when simplify y = simplify x` rather than just `when y = x`, or else the expression `(1+2) - (3+0)` would fail to be simplified down to 0. See my comment on the OP's original question. Other than this, good answer.

Comment: Had figured it out by now, but accepting answer for examples in case other people stumble across this! Thanks mate